# npm | node_modules on Users folder

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, node-modules

I'm little bit confused after try to solve how to install a module globally using npm.

I installed Node using a .dmg package from official site.
This is the final log.

Node was installed at

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

npm was installed at

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

From terminal I normally install modules using: for e.g.

```
npm install -g bower or npm install bower
```

But, I never could use

```
 bower
 -bash: bower: command not found
```

So I looked for

```
npm prefix
/Users/cleliodpaula
npm prefix -g
/Users/cleliodpaula/.node

npm ls
/Users/cleliodpaula
├─┬ appbuilder@2.1.1-61
```

How I can Install properly the Node, NPM and their modules?

edit:

I already installed it. But the installed bower, are not in the

```
/usr/local/bin
```

but, int the:

```
/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/
```

Comment: `npm install -g` is incorrect. Try `npm -g install`. If you are on linux/mac (*nix like OS) put sudo at the beginning.

Comment: I tried also, and nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

Bower is not part of NPM, you need to install it separately:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then you will have the executable in `/usr/local/bin/bower` and you will be able to use the `bower` command in Terminal.

The difference between `npm install -g` and `npm install` is that `npm install -g` installs the module globally (executable will be placed into `/usr/local/bin`). If you just use `npm install`, then NPM will install the package into `node_modules` directory under the current one. In that case you can execute the command as `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower`.

Edit: As I can see your NPM global path is set to `/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/`. If you want packages to be installed in `/usr/local/bin`, then change the configuration of NPM:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

You can also add `/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/` if you prefer packages to be installed in `/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/`:

```
export PATH=/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: I already installed it. But the installed bower, are not in the
    /usr/local/bin

but, int the:

    /Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/

Comment: @cleliodpaula Extended my answer. Are you sure you used the `-g` option? If you did, you should have the file in `/usr/local/bin/bower`.

Comment: Yes, I did it. the installed modules are in

    /Users/cleliodpaula/.node/lib/node_modules

Comment: @cleliodpaula Sorry, I just now see your global path is set to `/Users/cleliodpaula/.node/bin/`. Edited my answer. You can either change the global path, or add the current path to `PATH`.

Comment: thank you for your help. But what happens is I get a lot of errors, when I changed the prefix. Should I move the node folder too? Maybe I have 2 Node.js installed?

Comment: What's the permission of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`? You can use this command: `ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep node_modules`.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  5 24561         wheel    170 21 Mai 23:10 node_modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54392/discussion-between-gergo-erdosi-and-cleliodpaula).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Install Command Line Tools + Open Xcode.
The npm and node wasn't installed properly because that.